# How do I display only cities in the Google Maps API autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, html, api, maps

I've seen this question pop up a few times already, but was not able to implement this with my own existing code. At the moment the search box is displaying cities, provinces and even states. I want to limit the results to just cities. In other examples, they changed the types: [' '] to 'cities', but that is not working in my situation. The code I have been working on:

```
        <script>
        var autocomplete;
        function initialize() {
          autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
              /** @type {HTMLInputElement}                                  */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
              { types: ['geocode'] });
          google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
          });
        }
    </script>
```

And the input box:

```
    <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="locationField">
        <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter a city..." onFocus="geolocate()"            type="text"></input>
    </div>
```